# What terrestrial Gastropod (specifically snails) has the fastest reproductive rate?

Tags: evolution, molluscs, gastropod

I am looking to do a series of experiments to test the adaptation of snails to different environments (Controlled environments in a lab setting. No organisms would be released into the wild under any circumstances.), and to also test the potential rates of specialization to an environment or food source, and speciation in a snail species (obviously more experiments would have to be done with many species before the results could be generalized). To do this, I need a snail species that has a very short time between the oviposition and sexual maturity of the species, and that are not extremely difficult to raise or breed in a lab. Any help or leads would be appreciated!